# Azure ARM Template to export database to .bacpac file

Tags: sql, azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I wanted to know whether it is possible to write an ARM Template which exports a Azure SQL Database and stores the .bacpac file to any storage account?

I found the following link from Microsoft Documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export

But, in the above link there is no mention of doing it through ARM Template.
The end goal is to use this ARM template in a release pipeline and Database export and import should be done through the release pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is not meant to be done with arm templates, because [its a POST request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases%20-%20import%20export/export), not a PUT request. So you'd need to use Azure PowerShell\CLI to do that.

Comment: This URL helped. Thanks